# Option Group frame: can I add text boxes that are part of the frame instead of rad button options?

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls

Ok so this maybe a simple/silly question but I don't know so here goes:

In access let's say I want to have a frame control, so I click the option group button and add it to the desgin surface. However, I am not wanting to use this as a option group with radio button selection, instead I would like to add text boxes instead the frame, so that when I reference the frame, it references every control instead of it, hence the text boxes, cbo boxes, etc.....just as it would if they were radio option selections.

So can you do this?

I want whatever controls I add inside the frame to be easily referenced (i.e. make all controls visible just by using frameExample.visible = true) so that I can build my own tab control groupings.....

can this be done?

Thanks!

EDIT:

What I am trying to accomplish is having a form that includes a collection of controls (input controls - cbo boxes, text boxes, etc), that serve as the Main record information. These are saved to a table via an INSERT statement on button_click because this form is unbound.

Next I have 8 categories that are relative per each main record (and data that goes along with it). Each of these categories could have a sub form area and a button click that bring it's relative form into the sub form area. These sub forms would be unbound as well as I would just save data via SQL statement. So i know I could accomplish this by running the insert statement from the parent form, on the main collection control's data that would create the KeyID number, then run a SQL statement that would turn around and load that KeyID number right back onto the page in a hidden text box.

Then when I click one of the sub forms and load its relative collection of controls, I could then save that data along with KeyID for each of these sub-forms/tables.

SO......

I was wondering if instead you could define these controls as a collection so that you could hide and make visible all the ones you need on button clicks and avoid the need for additional forms (subs). I know that if a user enters data into a text box, and then somewhere along the way that box becomes hidden, the data still exists in it and still ends up in the SQL statement....

So I want all these controls to exist on the same form, but I thought what is I could encapsulate them into a frame like an option group, then I could call the frame and all the relative controls would be called up (made visible) as needed.

Sorry for the long explanation but I thought it would help.

Comment: A2003 allows you to group controls, which makes moving/resizing much easier, but I don't think there's any programmatic access to that. I don't use A2007, but it builds on that grouping and I believe makes it possible to do things with it programmatically. So, you might be able to do what you want in A2007 (not that that helps much when you're limited to A2003).

Comment: I find your emphasis on unbound forms for data that's stored in tables to be pretty problematic. You're working against the strengths of Access by insisting on doing things unbound, and that's always a red flag to me. It can lead to wasting a huge amount of time on things that would take no time at all if you just accepted the Access way of doing things. I don't like certain appearance aspects of Access, but can't justify spending clients' dollars on working around them, particularly when it's *me* and not the client who doesn't like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can do it with an Option Group, but what you are describing is pretty much a subform, yesno?

Comment: actually Remou, I was hoping that I could do this with an option group instead of a sub form, because I want to build my own tab control controls....instead of using the built in one. So what I want to be able to do is make collections of controls (text boxes, cbo boxes, etc) visible on non-visible, so that I can sort of make my own tab control. Sub-forms do not allow me to do this because I always use unbound forms and save data via SQL statements (INSERT/UPDATE), and with sub forms, I can't do this with more than one collection at a time.

Comment: Why do you want your own tab control, rather than existing tab controls? I ask, because it may be that there is a different solution available to you.

Comment: formatting....so it can match the look of the rest of the database. that is all. i can use the above approach that i mentioned in the EDIT, but if I can do this I would like to learn how.....but it just boils down to the asthetics.

Comment: this is because you cannot really format the tab control very much at all as far as I know. very limited in the properties window...

Comment: Are you aware that you can create a tab control without tabs and use any control you fancy, including images and labels to activate the page? Do you know that each control has a tag property that can be set to anything you like, including a string that will allow you to operate on a group of controls based on the value of the tag property?

Comment: Use the tab control and hide it. You can then provide whatever controls you want to drive the tab control. I have been doing this kind of thing since 1998 when I didn't like the available options for tab control appearance.

Comment: Also, although I do not think this is what you want, it is possible to group controls for design in versions >=2007 : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA010448531033.aspx

Comment: actually i think your suggestions are exactly what I am looking for, just did not know how to do it.... just go to each tab and set their visibility to 'no'? what code do you drive the tab selection with?? thanks!

Comment: so could you guys provide me with some instruction on how to get started, or point me to a website, etc....thanks fellas!

Answer (score 0):

Some examples of hiding the tab control from an app that went live in March 1998:

Tab driven by transparent command buttons over labels styled to look like colored command buttons:
[image]

Same approach, more buttons:
[image]

In this case, fake colored command buttons don't drive the tab, but insted show/hide the tab and a subform. In this case, the tab is actually driven by the listbox:
[image]

A view of when the tab is hidden and the subform revealed. The listbox drives navigation within the subform, which has a visible tab on it:
[image]

So, there's a lot that can be done without showing the tab control.

Comment: David - just to be clear before I flag this, does the information listed (company names, personal names, addresses, phone numbers, etc.) on the forms above have permission by Deloitte to be shared publically or is it all ficticious? In it's current format, it appears to be in serious violation of PII standards/ethics.

Comment: Ack! I used the wrong images -- I had images created with randomized data, but those aren't the ones. I've obscured every identifiable piece of data on the pictures. Thanks for pointing this out -- I don't know exactly how I ended up with the real screenshots on my website, but it probably happened when I migrated hosts a few years ago. Thankfully, nobody looks at my website!